# Download blur image before actual image gets downloaded in android

Tags: android

I want to do image downloading as whatsapp does as blur images appear and when we click on image clear image gets downloaded.I want to do the same kind of work in my android App.Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any image loading liabrary(Picasso,Glide or UIL)

Firstly load image of low quality say if you using Picasso

```
Picasso.with(this).load("....").resize(100,100).into(imageViews);
```

than on click load full image.

Comment: As a kind of thing i want to achieve is to have a compressed image first that will be downloaded in just few seconds as with slow net sometimes image takes time to download.For that time i want to make that blur image to appear to user and when image gets downloaded fully,Clear image appears. Is this possible with the method you are preferring to me

Comment: This is simply used to load. For your problem you have to make two folder one for small size image and other for large size image. Load small image when list inflate it will automatically blured.